# is it possible to make duble include in javascript and php?

Tags: php, javascript

I am using the following code to check if the user liked my facebook page or not ?

```
   <style>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</style>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script><script>google.load("jquery", "1");</script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Username="gagsallday", 
        Title="Join Our Facebook!", 
        Skin="01", 
        Time="30", 
        Wait="0", 
        Lang="en"
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="likeboxfbfanpro.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$().popupbox({ closeable: false });});</script>

<?
echo'<Center><Font Face="Tahoma"><Font size="10">Your Content Here!';
```

the last piece of code is where I should have my page contents on which is this one :

```
 <?
    echo'<Center><Font Face="Tahoma"><Font size="10">Your Content Here!';
```

my question is how can add this code to my page ? just like this ? it did not work because I can not include a file whiat already has include function inside it ? what I want is something like this, but how can I do it ?

```
<?php include('the-ablve-code-goes-here.php');?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
stuff goes here...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<center>` and `<font>`? seriously?

Comment: TWO `<font>` elements with on attribute each? Seriously?

Comment: I suspect that whatever the problem is, it has to do with how likeboxfbfanpro.js has been written. You haven't shared that code.

Comment: @Quentin: I think the first file is missing a `?>`.  Plus there's the issue of "scripts in `head`, content in `body`. Dunno though.

Comment: You need to use one font element only

<Font Face="Tahoma"><Font size="10">
to
<Font Face="Tahoma" size="10>

also you can include the code above, maybe there's something wrong on your syntaxes

Comment: @Manishearth — End of file works just as well as `?>`. Browsers can error recover from misplaced style errors (although it is very poor practise to ask them to do so).

Comment: That is not my problem guys ? my problem is how do I include the code to my website ?

Comment: @SuperNoob — Nothing in the JS that has been shared with us makes that requirement. Using multiple font elements is just uglier and more wasteful then using a single one.

Comment: @user1348777 — Oh. So your problem is "How can I have an include statement in some content included with an include statement?" not "How can I include the same thing twice?"

Comment: The code is working here [link](http://www.gagsallday.com/ff/FBpopup.php) but how do I include my page after the like ?

Comment: @Quentin: yeah, that's what I've wrote,he needs to turn that part of code to <font attribute=value attribute=value></font> also he already have a css, why don't he/she just put them there.

you need to include your file on the head (but make sure your code is correct)

`<html><head><?php include('the-above-code-goes-here'); ?></head><body></body</html>`

Answer (score 0):

> just like this ?

Yes.

> it did not work because I can not include a file whiat already has include function inside it ?

No. If it doesn't work, that isn't the reason. Maybe you don't have short tags turned on. Don't use short tags.

Comment: The code is working here link but how do I include my page instead of the "Your Content Here!"

Comment: Press backspace about 23 times then type your page. Use a PHP include if you want. Be aware that only inline content is allowed inside a font element.